# False estimates in a Poisson regression with continuous independent variable

Tags: poisson-regression, poisson-distribution

I am working with this data set: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i08 (DebTrivedi.rda.zip).

I fit a Poisson regression with two variables:

- ofp: Number of physician office visits
- numchron: Number of chronic condition

```
modelPoisson <- glm(formula = ofp ~ numchron,
                    family  = poisson(link = "log"),
                    data    = DebTrivedi)
```

I get these results:

```
summary(modelPoisson)
```

```
Call:
glm(formula = ofp ~ numchron, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = DebTrivedi)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-6.3140  -2.1822  -0.7042   0.8486  17.6593  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 1.409165   0.010124  139.20   <2e-16 ***
numchron    0.197902   0.004065   48.69   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 26943  on 4405  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 24767  on 4404  degrees of freedom
AIC: 37547

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

```
exp(coef(modelPoisson))
```

```
(Intercept)    numchron 
   4.092539    1.218843
```

The problem is: The results are wrong. The average number of physician office visits of people who do not have any chronic condition should be 3,38. I get this result when I treat the "numchron" variable as a categorical variable.

```
Call:
glm(formula = ofp ~ as.factor(numchron), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = DebTrivedi)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-5.0000  -2.1904  -0.7486   0.7770  17.0817  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           1.21860    0.01698  71.758   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)1  0.42277    0.02044  20.686   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)2  0.70794    0.02095  33.794   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)3  0.77409    0.02341  33.066   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)4  1.01044    0.02789  36.235   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)5  1.10116    0.03259  33.784   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)6  1.04806    0.05777  18.142   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)7  1.30713    0.11671  11.200   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(numchron)8 -0.52545    0.40836  -1.287    0.198    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 26943  on 4405  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 24394  on 4397  degrees of freedom
AIC: 37187

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

```
exp(coef(modelPoisson))
```

```
   (Intercept) as.factor(numchron)1 as.factor(numchron)2 as.factor(numchron)3 as.factor(numchron)4 
           3.3824391            1.5261816            2.0298082            2.1686239            2.7468075 
as.factor(numchron)5 as.factor(numchron)6 as.factor(numchron)7 as.factor(numchron)8 
           3.0076605            2.8521013            3.6955581            0.5912897
```

Could you please explain to me why it doesn't work in the first case with a continuous independent variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the true relationship between `numcron` and the log of the expected value of `ofc` is curvy but you fit a model that implies a linear relation, the estimates of the average value of `ofc` at each value of `numcron` will be inaccurate. The model uses the value of `ofc` for all values of `numcron` to estimate the slope and intercept, so the intercept will not only reflect the values of `ofc` when `numcorn = 0` but must also accommodate the restriction that the relationship between the log of the expected value of `ofc` and `numcron` be linear.

In contrast, when treating `numcron` as a categorical variable, the estimate of the intercept doesn't involve any data points where `numcron` is not 0, so the intercept will directly correspond to the average of `ofc` when `numcron = 0`. You can check this by removing some data points with nonzero values of `numcron`; you will see that the intercept remains identical in the categorical model but will change in the continuous linear model.